# Handling pymongo's AutoReconnect in a mongoengine (Django) app

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

mongoengine 0.4, django 1.3.1, uwsgi 1.0.2.1

Been banging my head against the wall on this one. I have a Django app that uses mongoengine. The mongodb server is a different box then my application server, and certain thing (firewall rule change, etc) will cause the connection to be lost.

I'd like to implement handling automatic reconnection in that case, so that my entire app doesn't crash when/if this happens. I was trying something along these lines: http://pastebin.com/HE8LSp5v (note this isn't my code, although I tried modifying it to work without success)

The code in that pastebin will successfully detect the failure and try to reconnect, but the for loop isn't iterated more than once normally, so what you see is a number of reconnect attempts every second, one for each uwsgi thread I'm guessing.

So I modified the code a bit (to be https://gist.github.com/1723790) and threw it on the bottom of my settings.py file. The result is the same for uwsgi and the dev server, so I'll use the dev server here for simplicity.

Launching the dev server, I get:

```
SETTING OVERRIDES
SETTING OVERRIDES DONE
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
SETTING OVERRIDES
SETTING OVERRIDES DONE
SETTING OVERRIDES
SETTING OVERRIDES DONE
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
SETTING OVERRIDES
SETTING OVERRIDES DONE
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3.1, using settings 'mucs.settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

With mongoengine running, I visit a page that makes a few requests into it. Works fine. I then shutdown mongodb and refresh the page. I get something like this printed to the screen:

```
(REQUEST IS STARTED)
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
PyMongo auto-reconnecting... could not connect to mucs-content:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Waiting 0.5 seconds. (Attempt 0)
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
PyMongo auto-reconnecting... could not connect to mucs-content:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Waiting 0.5 seconds. (Attempt 0)
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
PyMongo auto-reconnecting... could not connect to mucs-content:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Waiting 0.5 seconds. (Attempt 0)
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
PyMongo auto-reconnecting... could not connect to mucs-content:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Waiting 0.5 seconds. (Attempt 0)
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
PyMongo auto-reconnecting... could not connect to mucs-content:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Waiting 0.5 seconds. (Attempt 0)
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
WRAPPER ENTRY
PyMongo auto-reconnecting... could not connect to mucs-content:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Waiting 0.5 seconds. (Attempt 0)
WRAPPER ENTRY

[...]
```

This continues like this until I restart mongodb, and at that point the page is rendered correctly and things work fine. I don't want to put this code into production, because I'm not sure exactly what is going on here. It looks like it's may be recursing into the loop and not pulling the AutoReconnect exception that occurs back out correctly. I guess the next thing to try may be to examine the stack on each operation to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Hi,
Can you give some more details on what you mean by "the for loop isn't iterated more than once normally, so what you see is a number of reconnect attempts every second" ? Does the for loop stop iterating because the connection was successful or does something else happen? Maybe see if adding some more debugging messages inside the loop in the try/catch to see what happens when it actually is reconnecting.

Comment: and mongoengine version is ...? :)

Comment: using 0.4 now due to some model choice syntax changes in 0.5 they've reverted/enhanced in 0.6. Will upgrade to 0.6 when it comes out. I posted this to the mongoengine-users list as well and Ross (the mongoengine guy) will be looking into it post 0.6: https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/425 ...however, if you have or know or something that works now, I'm all ears :) could even go into mongoengine itself

Comment: Yeah, it's quite a wierd thing that is happening. I placed print statements around the code, and it's like the reconnection process is getting prematurely terminated. Normally I see the for loop enter just once (occasionally twice, but never more than that). I will be able to post some debugging info here tomorrow if that helps.

Comment: edited the question to add the exact code I was using, as well as some debugging info